# CSS3 target first paragraph inside a few container elements without using "of-type"

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can i style the first letter of the first paragraph in this code, without using ":nth-of-type" pseudo selectors?

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="breadcrumbs">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<article>
<section>
<h2>Page Name</h2>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Here, i'd like to style the first letter here</p>
</section>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `:nth-of-type` (`:first-of-type`)? See http://jsfiddle.net/PGQtA/ `section > p:first-of-type:first-letter` works like a charm.

Comment: Im using selectivizr with jquery and need to support older versions of IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to support older versions of IE, I'm afraid you're going to have to wrap the first letter in a `<span>` tag and style it that way.

```
<p><span class="letter">H</span>ere, i'd like to style the first letter here</p>
```

Or if your content is dynamic, you could use jQuery to wrap the first letter in a `<span>`, and the style will then be applied.

```
text = $('p').html();
first = $('<span>'+text.charAt(0)+'</span>').addClass('letter');
$('p').html(text.substring(1)).prepend(first);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does, i was trying to avoid using jquery to do the job, or add more  stuff to the markup, but thanks for your time.